# LaTeX annotation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, latex

I am trying to add a LaTeX annotation to a figure in MATLAB, but I'm running in to some problems. If I run

```
figure
annotation('textarrow', [0.3, 0.6], [0.3, 0.6], 'String', '$$\tau_{\mathrm{abc}}$$', 'interp', 'latex')
```

I would expect an arrow with the correct annotation. That is indeed what I get, but I also receive the following warning messages:

```
Warning: Unable to interpret TeX string "$$\tau_{\mathrm{abc}}$$" 
> In scribe.textarrow.createTextArrow>localChangePosition at 409
  In scribe.textarrow.schema>localSetToText at 357
  In scribe.textarrow.createTextArrow at 152
  In scribe.textarrow.textarrow at 11
  In annotation at 149 
Warning: incomplete command in TeX text string:
'$$\tau_{\mathrm{abc}}$$' 
> In scribe.textarrow.createTextArrow>localChangePosition at 409
  In scribe.textarrow.schema>localSetToText at 357
  In scribe.textarrow.createTextArrow at 152
  In scribe.textarrow.textarrow at 11
  In annotation at 149
```

So, my question is, why do I get these warnings, and how do I correct the underlying problem?

Comment: Looks like  Matlab doesn't like "\mathrm". Without that no warning appears

Comment: Yes. However, `\mathrm` should technically work for MATLAB. Also, if I substitute `\mathrm` for some other stuff like `\frac` I also get warnings.

Comment: @riklund: Perhaps try `$\tau_{\rm abc}$`.

Comment: @Werner, that also gives a warning (plus it does not produce the correct text on the graph).

Comment: Personal opinion after struggling a lot with LaTex on Matlab, use Tex. You can do almost anything with it and it uses the accepted syntax rather than the messed up one Matlab adapted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the interpreter before the string.
This works

```
annotation('textarrow', [0.3, 0.6], [0.3, 0.6], 'interpreter', 'latex', 'String', '$$\tau_{\mathrm{abc}}$$')
```

And also you need the long name interpreter instead of its abbreviation.